# what is the best way of getting the ICollectionView when working in mvvm pattern?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

when using mvvm pattern, when we have lists we use ObservableCollection<>.

my question is when should i call to

`CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(theCollection);`

to get the view that i can filter and sort and do some other cool stuff.

if i dont work with mvvm i'll do it in window.load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just need to make sure that you call the

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefualtView([your observable collection])
```

after the collection reference initiated...

and dont call it more than once cause there is no reason

Answer (score -2):

For MVVM is better use a ViewModel with property of type ObservableCollection. In this viewmodel you can implement your functionality.

Comment: yea ok and how should i perform filtering and sorting????
ObservableCollection does not have those capabilities, IListCollectionView has them.

Comment: You can use OrderBy extesions methods.

Comment: why should i touch my collection when the collectionview can order itself?

Comment: what about filtering, i don't think you should mass up your collection